# using net.sf.json-lib, how could a add "[0]" as JSONObject string element?

Tags: json, json.net

I am using using net.sf.json-lib, when I try to add string element with value "[0]", it will become an array automatically! how could a keep "[0]" as string, but not array?

```
JOSNObject json = new JSONObject();
// I want the value alway be string
// even if the value is "[0]"
json.element("name", "[0]");
// here it will become an array!!!
```

What should I do to stop such automatically convert?

Thanks

Comment: Get a better JSON converter.  It should be automatically escaped to `\uXXXX` where XXXX is the Unicode value for `[` and `]`.

Comment: could you recommend some better JSON converter ? Thanks

Comment: Newtonsoft.json (http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) is highly regarded in the community.

Comment: See the [JSON web site](http://www.json.org/) for a list of available JSON implementations.

Comment: Thanks All. I tries FastJson, and it works well.